# Do desktop GUIs (Graphical User Interfaces) written in C++, C#, Java, etc use the concept of DOM or something similar, like all web or mobile GUIs do?

Tags: java, c#, c++, user-interface, dom

Its extremely common to heavily understand and use concepts of the Document Object Model (DOM), to create various kinds of GUIs for web and mobile applications. I was wondering though, whether GUIs for desktops, embedded systems, other electronic devices and so on (programmed using C++, C#, Java, Python, etc) use this concept of DOM or some similar "object model" with APIs (application programming interfaces) in order to "render and display" visual and graphical contents on their screens?

Comment: This is so ridiculously broad, it's impossible to answer.  Some GUI libraries are DOM-like, and some aren't.  Pretty much any OS-level GUI will be lower-level than any kind of abstraction such as DOM.

Comment: There's quite a bit of variety, there's software rendered UIs, hardware rendered UIs (which at a low level might manipulate pixel data directly). For Windows the APIs based on GDI (Winforms, winapi) use a paint event to redraw part of the screen, each control is asked to draw itself, and custom controls can draw shapes, lines, text, or images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are an insane number of ways to do it.  Graphical OS's usually provide one or more widget tool kits, which can include configuration files, binding engines, or just APIs to create widgets of various kinds.  The windowing system acts a bit like the browser environment.

In graphical games and other less OS bound apps, often you'll write your own widgeting toolkit on top of your GPU accelerated surface, or use a graphics toolkit that writes it for you.  Companies that put out multiple games or similar will have a code base that makes their style of game UI a bit easier to stand up.  This gets closer to pushing pixels; but if you want decent performance and nice transitions you are actually often going to be pushing geometry to GPU code, not pixels.

Animating 60 fps smooth transitions on 4k monitors on a CPU is impractical; doing soon the GPU is easy. So languages that cannot interact with the GPU easily often end up with intermediate libraries or frameworks doing it for them.

Other programs will literally have an embedded chrome engine and spew out HTML and bind callbacks into it.

If your UI is more static, pushing pixels from the CPU is feasible.  Even then, the content often ends up copied onto the GPU by the OS/windowing framework, so grabbing an entire window and moving it around is smooth and cheap.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I really appreciate the variety of ways of rendering GUIs that you have highlighted. I thought that the DOM was the only way or default standard of rendering visuals and GUIs. I now realize that there are several other ways of doing so.